# Xamarin Forms my app not working on Android 12

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

My application works for all versions of Android except 12, Xamarin Forms does not show me the problem but Play Console showed me, I don't know how to solve this problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0Yuq.png)

I hope to solve this problem

Comment: Did you not test your app locally with an Android 12 device? You're providing way too little information for anyone to be able to help you effectively. Please provide all necessary information. Just saying that something doesn't work and showing an exception is not sufficient. Please also don't post exceptions or code as images, always use text: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There could be many problems with the code, and that error is really ambiguous.

When working with Android you need to know that there are many versions, as you can see in the version history: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history

There are some functionalities, such as the NotificationCompat Builder that change between versions. You should review your code and see which methods might differ given the version.

You are probably going to need to make this comparison:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.S)
```

At some point in your code and make two different versions of a functionality for it to work on multiple devices.

I recommend to test on different physical or emulated devices with versions at least from Android Oreo upwards to cover most phones currently in the market.

Best regards.